# Finding the length of a dataframe for a moving time period for a particular category

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have two DataFrames:

df:

```
    Name    Date_1  Date_2
0   Alan    2013-06-21  2013-06-26
1   Bob     2011-01-29  2011-02-01
2   Chris   2010-11-15  2010-11-17
3   Bob     2016-03-14  2016-03-16
4   Doug    2011-03-07  2011-03-10
5   Elijah  2011-02-24  2011-03-01
6   Bob     2011-01-03  2011-01-13
7   Bob     2011-02-07  2011-02-25
8   Frank   2014-07-21  2014-07-23
9   Chris   2011-02-18  2011-02-22
10  Doug    2010-09-13  2010-09-17
11  Chris   2011-01-15  2011-01-19
12  George  2010-06-29  2010-06-30
```

And df1:

```
        Date        Name    Period
12971   2015-08-18  Alan    2015-08-16
12972   2015-08-19  Alan    2015-08-17
12973   2015-08-20  Alan    2015-08-18
12974   2015-08-21  Alan    2015-08-19
12975   2015-08-22  Alan    2015-08-20
12976   2015-08-23  Alan    2015-08-21
12977   2015-08-24  Alan    2015-08-22
12978   2015-08-25  Alan    2015-08-23
12979   2015-08-26  Alan    2015-08-24
12980   2015-08-27  Alan    2015-08-25
12981   2015-08-28  Alan    2015-08-26
12982   2015-08-29  Alan    2015-08-27
```

Both dataframes are thousand of rows long, this is just a sample, what I want to do is to find the number of rows in df, where Date is less than Date_2, Date_1 is more than Period for a particular name in df.

I have done the following, which achieves the result but is very slow:

```
df1['Volume'] = df1.apply(lambda x: len(df[(df['Name'] == x['Name']) & (
df['Date_1'] < x['Period']) & (df['Date_2'] > x['Date'])]), axis=1)
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: You could try instead do it row by row, tear it in parts and asynchronously do all parts at once. Is it stored in database or in a file?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change your supplied table slightly as your current version does not have any overlap. I assume you want to do the following:

The schema is simple, first do outer join on both table, pivot on the results and finally left join on the dataframe which you are interested in. This should be faster than your approach, however, it may be more memory intensive.

### Parse the data

The first things are just to perform some basic parsing of the data that you supplied and put it in the dataframe (you can probably skip this I am supplying this for traceability):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

# First set tables
table = """    Name    Date_1  Date_2
0   Alan    2013-06-21  2013-06-26
1   Bob     2011-01-29  2011-02-01
2   Chris   2010-11-15  2010-11-17
3   Bob     2016-03-14  2016-03-16
4   Doug    2011-03-07  2011-03-10
5   Elijah  2011-02-24  2011-03-01
6   Bob     2011-01-03  2011-01-13
7   Bob     2011-02-07  2011-02-25
8   Frank   2014-07-21  2014-07-23
9   Chris   2011-02-18  2011-02-22
10  Doug    2010-09-13  2010-09-17
11  Chris   2011-01-15  2011-01-19
12  George  2010-06-29  2010-06-30"""

table2 = """        Date        Name    Period
12971   2015-08-18  Alan    2015-08-16
12972   2015-08-19  Alan    2015-08-17
12973   2015-08-20  Alan    2015-08-18
12974   2015-08-21  Alan    2015-08-19
12975   2015-08-22  Alan    2015-08-20
12976   2015-08-23  Alan    2015-08-21
12977   2015-08-24  Alan    2015-08-22
12978   2015-08-25  Alan    2015-08-23
12979   2015-08-26  Alan    2015-08-24
12980   2015-08-27  Alan    2015-08-25
12981   2015-08-28  Alan    2015-08-26
12982   2015-08-29  Alan    2015-08-27
12983   2013-06-24  Alan    2013-06-25"""

# Prepare tables in format that makes date lookups easier
series = pd.read_csv(StringIO(table))['    Name    Date_1  Date_2'].apply(lambda x: ["".join(re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9-]",i)) for i in x.split(" ") if re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9-]",i) != []])
df = pd.DataFrame(series.values.tolist(), columns = ["index", "Name", "Date_1","Date_2"])
df["Date_1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_1"])
df["Date_2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_2"])

series = pd.read_csv(StringIO(table2))['        Date        Name    Period'].apply(lambda x: ["".join(re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9-]",i)) for i in x.split(" ") if re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9-]",i) != []])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(series.values.tolist(), columns = ["index", "Date", "Name","Period"])
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df1["Period"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Period"])
```

### Outer join

Outer join is simple on `Name` column:

```
outer = pd.merge(df1,df, on="Name",how="outer")
```

### Merge on df1 (assumed requirement)

Simply first pivot on the data by the `Name`, `Date` and `Period` and count these. Then `reset_index` and merge with the original table, when lookup is not found I assume `0` value.

```
# Pivot table
pivot = outer[(outer["Date_1"] < outer["Period"]) & (outer["Date_2"] > outer["Date"])].pivot_table(index=["Name","Date","Period"],
                                                                                    values= ["Date_1"],
                                                                                    aggfunc="count").reset_index()
# Rename columns for merging
pivot.columns = [["Name","Date","Period","Volume"]]

pd.merge(df1,pivot, how = "left", on=["Name","Date","Period"]).fillna(0)
```

### Merge on df (for completeness)

```
# Pivot table
pivot = outer[(outer["Date_1"] < outer["Period"]) & (outer["Date_2"] > outer["Date"])].pivot_table(index=["Name"],
                                                                                    values= ["Date"],
                                                                                    aggfunc="count").reset_index()
# Rename columns for merging
pivot.columns = [["Name","Volume"]]

pd.merge(df,pivot, how = "left", on="Name").fillna(0)
```